# How to integrate google admob with flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

How do I integrate with the Admob with flutter app?

Actually, I want, show Google Ads at the bottom of my application that's why I browsed for it and got the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXYmbTBT3Yo) and followed that but dunno why it's not working..!!!
getting issues and I'm unable to catch it, 
I searched for this issue but couldn't get any solution

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "ca-app-pub-3280358404648281~7983595363");
    myBanner..load()..show();
    return Scaffold(
      .....
    );
  }
}

MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo = MobileAdTargetingInfo(
  keywords: <String>['game', 'babilok'],
  contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
  birthday: DateTime.now(), //deprecated
  childDirected: false,
  designedForFamilies: false, //deprecated
  gender: MobileAdGender.male, // or MobileAdGender.female, MobileAdGender.unknown (deprecated)
  testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
);


BannerAd myBanner = BannerAd(
  // Replace the testAdUnitId with an ad unit id from the AdMob dash.
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
  // https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads
  adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-3280358404648281/6455246498",
  size: AdSize.smartBanner,
  targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
  listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
    print("BannerAd event is $event");
  },
);
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest 
    <application 
        <activity
            ....
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3280358404648281~*********"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
            android:value="true"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Console log:

```
D/DynamitePackage( 3049): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraMobileAdsSettingManagerCreatorImpl

I/WebViewFactory( 3049): Loading com.google.android.webview version 76.0.3809.132 (code 380913205)

D/ResourcesManager( 3049): creating new AssetManager and set to /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/base.apk

I/cr_LibraryLoader( 3049): Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps 3902-3904)

I/chromium( 3049): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(51)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0

I/cr_LibraryLoader( 3049): Expected native library version number "76.0.3809.132", actual native library version number "76.0.3809.132"

I/cr_BrowserStartup( 3049): Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true

D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 3049): CM callback handler got msg 524290

E/libEGL  ( 3049): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

E/chromium( 3049): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(343)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

W/cr_media( 3049): Requires BLUETOOTH permission

D/DynamitePackage( 3049): Instantiating com.google.android.gms.ads.ChimeraAdManagerCreatorImpl

E/chromium( 3049): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(343)] eglChooseConfig failed with error EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE

I/Ads     ( 3049): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("C93E3D5EBB200061812734814B28CC4D") to get test ads on this device.

W/AudioCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L1

W/AudioCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime audio/mpeg-L2

W/AudioCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime audio/x-ms-wma

W/AudioCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime audio/x-ima

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/wvc1

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/wvc1

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv7

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/x-ms-wmv8

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/sorenson

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime video/mp43

W/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es

I/VideoCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es

W/AudioCapabilities( 3049): Unsupported mime audio/ac3

W/art     ( 3049): mismatched stack depths (depth=1, incoming depth=2)

I/DynamiteModule( 3049): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:20461

I/DynamiteModule( 3049): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 20461

D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler( 3049): CM callback handler got msg 524290

E/IMGSRV  ( 3049): :0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Switching psTex 0x8c777840 to XBGR

E/IMGSRV  ( 3049): :0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Switching psLevel 0x9f1e0800 to XBGR

E/IMGSRV  ( 3049): :0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Switching psTex 0x8c7778e0 to XBGR

E/IMGSRV  ( 3049): :0: ComputeFrameBufferCompleteness: Switching psLevel 0x8c74f000 to XBGR
Syncing files to device GT I9500...                              3,800ms (!)
E/FA      ( 3049): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
W/art     ( 3049): Suspending all threads took: 9.252ms

  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on GT I9500 is available at: //http://127.0.0.1:65429/WyO_d_pLZrY=/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".
I/FA      ( 3049): App measurement is starting up, version: 14711
I/FA      ( 3049): To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA      ( 3049): To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
I/FA      ( 3049):   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.google_fire_admob
E/FA      ( 3049): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. 

E/FA      ( 3049): Uploading is not possible. App measurement disabled
W/Ads     ( 3049): Not retrying to fetch app settings
W/flutter ( 3049): onAdFailedToLoad: 0
I/Ads     ( 3049): Ad failed to load : 0
I/flutter ( 3049): BannerAd event is MobileAdEvent.failedToLoad
I/FA      ( 3049): Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
E/FA      ( 3049): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. 
I/Timeline( 3049): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2669e1b1 time:9049317
E/FA      ( 3049): Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled. 
V/ActivityThread( 3049): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{50bb604 token=android.os.BinderProxy@2669e1b1 {com.example.google_fire_admob/com.example.google_fire_admob.MainActivity}} show : true
```

Comment: Have you tried a test adUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add google-service.json. If you don't know how can find this JSON. Please follow these steps;

- Create a firebase application from firebase.google.com
- Click settings button from the left of the screen > project settings
- Add app and after you can download google-service.json

And you can find more information from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

Finally please use test ad unit ids for the test. Admob doesn't fill new unit ids quickly.

Comment: Can you tried admob test unit ids? And you can share console log with us because admob show error detail of fail

Comment: Yeah you need add firebase admob because admod moved to Firebase

Comment: I have added my console log, now you can see my console log,

Comment: look at this : E/FA      ( 3049): GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.

Do you change ca-app-pub-3280358404648281~"*********" this? And you can add <string name="google_app_id">your app id</string> into resource

And Can you change your unit ads with this "adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,"

Comment: <string name="google_app_id">your app id</string>,`google_app_id`  Where will it be found? and where to add this line

Comment: you can find from Firebase app settings. And you can find from google-service.json. This google_app_id will be added into resource > value > strings.xml

Comment: Is it okay??  ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Babilok</string>

  
    <string name="google_app_id">1:496111449761:android:4e0d86866009fc4c</string>
</resources>```

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much. now It's working fine. [See_Here_Admob_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onuyo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly because unlike the tutorial you have linked to, you are calling `myBanner..load()..show();` before `FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize` completes. Try chaining `.then((_) { myBanner..load()..show(); });` to the initialize call.

Comment: I still didn't understand. just only understood, haven't added google-service.json file.could you please explain with the complete code.